# One source file change cause full project rebuild on Visual 2010 after Visual 2013 install

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, build-process

Since I have installed [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013), any modification to a source (c or c++) file cause a full rebuild of my [visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010) projects.

If build again without modification, the project is seen as up-to-date and is not build again. It is a different behavior than all the rebuild issues I saw on SO.

I have already tracked for missing files using [Dbgview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) but there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem is indeed due to the installation of visual studio 2013.

First I increased the verbosity in visual studio

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSbuild project...
```

And observed the following output that when I change any file

> C:\SOMEPATH\someidl.idl will be compiled as C:\PROJECTPACT\DLLDATA.C
>   was modified at 07/13/2014 11:23:24 AM. (TaskId:18)

[This request on microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763929/incremental-build-of-idl-files-behavior-changes-after-installing-visual-studio-2012) exhibit the same behavior.
It seems this is due to a fix introduced in 2012 to the global MSbuild, and affects only projects with IDL files. From the dev

> During the development of VS2012, we fixed several issues with
>   tracker.exe. This tool tracks the reads and writes of the build
>   systems. One of such improvements allowed us to properly track 64bit
>   midl. However, this improvement also started tracking dlldata.c. In
>   VS2012, we counteracted it by adding logic to ignore dlldata.c. This
>   leaves VS2010 showing dlldata.c.

The solution provided is to modify VS2010 build system to use part of VS2013 build system. In the file `%ProgramFiles%\msbuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets`

the line

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MIDL" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

should be replaced with

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MIDL" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.v110, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```